# SQL build search query to match multiple ids

Tags: sql

I've become stuck on particular problem of finding common items between tables. I have to works with these 3 tables - People can own have more than one home.

I want to find all people that have owned the same home as "John Doe"

```
Persons
    +------+------------------+----------+
    | id   | firsname         | lastname |
    +------+------------------+----------+
    |    1 | John             | Doe      |
    +------+------------------+----------+

Home
+------+------------------+-----------+
| h_id |     address      | year_built|
+------+------------------+-----------+
|    1 | 1233 SQL PL NW   | 1995      | 
+------+------------------+-----------+

Ownership
+-----------+------------------+
| person_id |     house_id     |
+-----------+------------------+
|    1      |         1        |
+-----------+------------------+
```

My current thoughts on what the query should go is that I check Persons.id matches the ownership.id then find the house.id and compare it two a some Person2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to go

```
persons -> 
    ownership -> 
       ownership that's not John Doe -> 
         back to persons again
```

This should do it

```
SELECT p2.id,
       p2.first_name,
       p2.last_name
FROM   persons p 
   INNER JOIN ownership o 
     ON p.id = o.person_id 
   INNER JOIN ownership o2 
     ON p.id <> o2.person_id 
        AND o.house_id = o2.house_id 
   INNER JOIN persons p2 
     ON o2.person_id = p2.id 
WHERE p.id = 1
```

as dtbarne notes the where clause assume you know the ID. If you want you change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE p.first_name = 'John' and p.Last_name = 'Doe'
```

The problem there of course is if two records in person share the name you'll get multiple results so you want to add House information to the `SELECT` clause to differentiate

Comment: Assumes you know the ID of John Doe.

Comment: You don't know the name of John Doe, but you have the id of p2. 
Also, thank you very much for you response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  You want to find all of the people who own a house where the house Id is in the list of the subquery, which is all house(s) owned by John Doe.

Note: column name firsname (sic) matches your question, may be a typo.

```
select po.*
from Persons po
inner join ownership oo
on po.id = oo.person_id
where house_id in (select house_id 
  from ownership o 
  inner join persons p
  on p.id = o.person_id
  where p.firsname = 'John' and p.lastname = 'Doe'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Persons.*
FROM Persons, Ownership
WHERE Persons.id = Ownership.person_id
    AND Ownership.house_id = 
        (SELECT Home.h_id
         FROM Home, Persons
         WHERE Home.h_id = Ownership.house_id
            AND Ownership.person_id = id
            AND Persons.firsname = 'John'
            AND Persons.lastname = 'Doe' LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Is it considered more stylistically correct to use JOINs?(Honest question, still learning)

Comment: Fair question, probably worth a post itself. I find it easier to read and work with the syntax I posted, although I get the sense I'm in the minority. :)

Comment: Yes ANSI 92 style joins are perferred. At the very least you see when you're missing a join and don't end up with a Cartesian product. For example Home isn't joined to anything

Comment: By the way, the syntax I used is still an INNER JOIN. It's just a different way to write it.

Comment: @Conrad Frix Ummm...that post proves that they are indeed identical. EDIT: I see you removed that comment.

Comment: @dtbarne You noticed :) I was looking for [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338) which included the bit about `*<` vs `Left Join` and grabbed the wrong post. Ended up deleting it because and I couldn't edit it in time.

Comment: query is incorrect. the limit 1 will make it return only one house (and not necessarily the one Joe currently owns).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM persons p 
   INNER JOIN ownership o 
     ON p.id = o.person_id  
     INNER JOIN Home h 
     ON o.house_id = h.h_id 
WHERE p.firsname = 'John' and p.lastname = 'Doe'
```