# Stored Procedure vs UDF and difference between Inner join ","

Tags: sql

What is the difference between Stored Procedure and UDF. T

**1. Difference between Stored Procedure and UDF having same query.**
i.e.

`SP
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Customer
END`

`Function
Return Select * FROM Customer`

**2. What is the difference between**

```
`select * from emp, dept where emp.DeptId = dept.DeptId`
```

`select * from emp inner join dept on emp.DeptId = dept.DeptId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1.` http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=329
`2.` There's no difference, maybe on performance.
 The second style is the old fashion Join. For old Fashion outer join they used **+**, `select * from emp, dept where +emp.DeptId = dept.DeptId`, Oracle now say it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd one, see [SQL JOIN: is there a difference between USING, ON or WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338). 
Basically, one is "old style" "JOIN-in-the WHERE". Using explicit JOIN is preferred and is a later ANSI standard

For stored proc vs udf, there are a lot of answers under "related" on the right hand side of this page...