# Query from 2 pseudotables, hosted in the same real table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let there are 2 tables. To query the rows, which have the same IDs, you have to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A, Table2 B WHERE A.id = B.id
```

Now let the tables be merged into one global table, with an added ex-table column. So, query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

now looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM GlobalTable WHERE tableId = 1
```

But how the first query should look now?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A, Table2 B WHERE A.id = B.id
```

?

Comment: You should never use implicit joins, they are a poor programming practice which often creates subtle bugs in your queries.  They were replaced almost 20 years ago for good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One table should store one entity. There is no such thing as a "one true lookup table" or "global table". Nor should you consider an EAV. This question assumes all your tables have the same layout...

However, I look forward to more rep later when it doesn't work properly so...

You should use explicit JOINs to separate filter and join conditions

```
Select *
from
   GlobalTable A
   JOIN
   GlobalTable B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.tableId = 1 AND B.tableId = 2
```

If you need to do an OUTER JOIN, then you can write this

```
Select *
from
   (SELECT * FROM GlobalTable WHERE tableId = 1) A
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM GlobalTable WHERE tableId = 2) B ON A.id = B.id
```

I'd suggest using an indexed view though to persist "tableA" and "tableB" as separate objects to avoid this continual filtering. Or don't merge them...

Comment: Could you please give some clue, why the answer below shouldn't work and JOIN should?

Comment: @noober: works the same, but JOIN is better. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338