# SQl queries left join not giving accurate results

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to join two tables (USERS AND USERS_ROLES) based on their role id I put the left join on following query

> users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id
>   but the output is not correct of users_roles.fk_role_id coulmun and shows NULL where it should display the id of users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id that is 4 (at most places) because on users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id the value of users_roles.fk_role_id = 4

Kindly let me know how can i fix that so my query should result the exact vlaues of ids where they match,
Thanks

```
SELECT users.id, users.v_first_name, users.v_last_name, user_facility.fk_facility_id,users.fk_tenant_id, marital_status.v_marital_status, 
            users.v_blood_type, NOW(),users_roles.fk_role_id
            FROM users
            LEFT JOIN (user_facility, marital_status, users_roles) ON
            users.id = user_facility.fk_user_id AND users.fk_marital_status_id=marital_status.id AND  users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it is what you get by first implicitly inner-joining 3 tables and then explicitly left-joining the result to a 4th table only if 3 conditions relevant to all of the 3 inner-joinded tables are matched (i.e. when 3rd condition is false, nothing is joined from either of the 2 remaining tables)

i strongly suggest **not to combine implicit and explicit joins**, i personally use explicit joins all the time:

if you need an outer join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_facility ON users.id = user_facility.fk_user_id
LEFT JOIN marital_status ON users.fk_marital_status_id=marital_status.id
LEFT JOIN users_roles ON users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id
```

if you need an inner join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
JOIN user_facility ON users.id = user_facility.fk_user_id
JOIN marital_status ON users.fk_marital_status_id=marital_status.id
JOIN users_roles ON users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id
```

or if you prefere implicit inner joins for some obscure reason:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users,
     user_facility,
     marital_status,
     users_roles
WHERE users.id = user_facility.fk_user_id
  AND users.fk_marital_status_id=marital_status.id
  AND users.id = users_roles.fk_user_id
```

(implicit outer joins are getting deprecated in all RDBMS as far as i know)

Comment: Well thanks i am beginner and in a learning stage your answer is quite better now all the checks are being performed accordingly just the way i wanted and no null results by using explicit joins. So, from now onwards should i always use this style if i have to join with multiple tables? Is it a good coding practice?

Comment: [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/1176601) [is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/1176601) [much](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7810515/1176601) [debate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6891422/1176601) considering implicit vs explicit joins, but as for combining them that would definitelly be bad coding practice

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `AND` operator when used with `Left` or `Right` join gives different result. You should be clear what you are trying to accomplish..[See this](http://techpint.com/programming/how-sql-joins-works)

Answer (score 1):

When it shows `NULL` it means there isn't a correspondency (relation) between all tables in the `JOIN` clause.

If you want to show only the ones that have relations in all tables, use `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.v_first_name,
       u.v_last_name,
       uf.fk_facility_id,
       u.fk_tenant_id,
       ms.v_marital_status,
       u.v_blood_type,
       NOW(),
       ur.fk_role_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_facility uf ON u.id = uf.fk_user_id
INNER JOIN marital_status ms ON u.fk_marital_status_id=ms.id
INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON u.id = ur.fk_user_id
```

Comment: okay means its happening because of other checks (i checked it by removing them and you are right) just one last question if i put insert on above to the mentioned query how can i put check as on this query that it checks and store only those data of month/year whose data wasn't entered in it before. Thanks, (If you say i'll post another question for it)

Comment: @softgenic that might be another question. And you'll need to explain it better for all of us to understand it.

Comment: kindly check this url and see if you can help thanks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144468/filteration-on-inserting-as-per-date-month-and-exsiting-record-of-userid