# Sequel to get select EVERY input

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables

```
CREATE TABLE guest(

name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(

 roomname varchar(100),
 wallcolor varchar(100),
 rating int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
 );

 CREATE TABLE reservation(

 name varchar(100),
 roomname varchar(100),
 day varchar(100),
 moveinday int,
 moveoutday int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
  FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
  FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
 );
```

I am trying to write a query to find the guests who reserved EVERY "LakeView" room

I tried the following

```
SELECT g.name
FROM guest g, reservation r, room rr
WHERE rr.name = g.name
AND rr.roomname = "LakeView"
GROUP BY g.name
```

This does not seem to list out every room. How could I gix this?

Input:

```
  insert into guest values ('Andrew', 1);
  insert into guest values ('Jack', 4);
  insert into guest values ('Jake', 4);
  insert into room values ('LakeView', 'white', 10);
  insert into room values ('BayView', 'blue', 4);
  insert into reservation values ('Andrew', 'LakeView', 'Friday', 10,15);
  insert into reservation values ('Jake', 'LakeView', 'Monday', 10,16);
  insert into reservation values ('Jack', ' BayView', 'Tuesday', 11,15);
```

Desired output is

```
   Andrew 
   Jake
```

Comment: could you provide with some input output?

Comment: What did you actually mean by this term **who reserved EVERY "LakeView" boat** ?

Comment: that was a typo. check the edit for sample input and expected output

Comment: look it's wrong probably **WHERE rr.name = g.name**. you are matching the roomname with guest name.

Comment: am I right @Jonathan Bishop

Comment: What do you mean by `"EVERY "LakeView" room"? Is there more than one LakeView room, and how do we tell if a guest has reserved them all?

Comment: And how could there be more than one, if `roomname` is the primary key? That means it has to be unique.

Comment: i want to know every guest that reserved a lakeview room. its just a type ofroom. i could have 5 lakeview rooms. i want to know all 5 guests who reserved it, if 5 have reserved it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT 
guest.name
FROM guest INNER JOIN 
reservation ON reservation.name = guest.name
INNER JOIN room ON reservation.roomname = room.roomname
WHERE reservation.roomname = "LakeView"
GROUP BY guest.name
```

**Here I've highlighted your mistakes:**

[image]

- You tried to match **rr.name with g.name**. That means you are
  matching roomname with guest name which you didn't want (so far I
  guess).
- Another mistake is you are only checking "**LakeView**" only in room
  table entries. So other guests who haven't reserved **LakeView** room
  might appear in the final result set. You also need to filter those
  records from reservation table which have **LakeView** roomname.

Here's your query modified based on the above observations:

**Solution 2:**

```
SELECT g.name
FROM guest g, reservation r, room rr
WHERE r.name = g.name
AND rr.roomname = "LakeView"
AND r.roomname = "LakeView"
GROUP BY g.name;
```

**N:B:** Solution 1 is encouraged to use. Try to avoid implicit joins which are stated in solution 2.

> I personally think the INNER JOIN is better, because it is more
>   readable. It shows better the relations between the table. You got
>   those relations in the join, and you do the filtering in the WHERE
>   clause. This separation makes the query more readable.

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891422/which-is-better-implicit-or-explicit-join).

Comment: Please don't encourage the user of implicit joins. Use ANSI `JOIN ... ON` syntax in answers.

Comment: You are right @Barmar. But I just wanted to help him the way he approached. Later I can add suggestion on building a query USING ANSI `JOIN....ON`. Thanks.

Comment: this seems to only return 1 guest who reserved. i want to know every guest that reserved a lakeview room

Comment: check your guest table whether **Jake** exists or not.

Comment: in your sample input there's no entry for **Jake**.

Comment: I've updated the query based on INNER JOIN as Barmar pointed out. Please check this query. @JonathanBishop

Answer (score 0):

if you using php-mysql then it will be help

```
$qry=mysql_query("select name from reservation where roomname='LakeView'");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($qry)
{
  echo $result['name'];
 }
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? The query is the same no matter what language is used. And you shouldn't use the obsolete `mysql` extension, use either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the 'name' column in the reservation table is the name of the guest or guests. If this is true it sounds like you only need the reservation table for the purposes of this query, but if you wanted to combine them all anyway:

`select
    rv.name as Guest
from room as r
    left join reservation as rv on rv.roomname = r.roomname
    left join guest as g on g.name = rv.name
where
    rv.roomname = 'LakeView'`