# Another way to write this query

Tags: mysql, wamp

Whats another way to write this query?

My server takes a lot of time to execute this one:

```
SELECT c.id, c.franquicia_id, f.name, CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) 
       contacto, c.created, DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d-%m-%Y') fecha 
FROM franquicias f, contacts c where f.id = c.franquicia_id 
 and c.created = (
                   select max(c2.created) 
                   from contacts c2 
                   WHERE c2.franquicia_id = c.franquicia_id
                 ) 
 and f.contract_id=2 
ORDER BY created DESC 
limit 10
```

Comment: I try to avoid correlated subqueries when possible. _...and 80's style joins._

Comment: Check if contacts.created - indexed. Run "explain" on your query

Comment: Generally, an uncorellated subquery will run faster than a correlated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of the subquery will only need run once for the entire query, rather than for each row of the outer query.

```
SELECT c.id, c.franquicia_id, f.name
   , CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) AS contacto
   , c.created, DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d-%m-%Y') AS fecha 
FROM contacts AS c 
INNER JOIN franquicias AS f
   ON c.franquicia_id = f.id
    AND f.contract_id=2 
WHERE (c.franquicia_id, c.created) IN (
          SELECT franquicia_id, max(created) 
          FROM contacts
          GROUP BY franquicia_id
) 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Alternatively, the subquery can instead be used in an additional JOIN for filtering.

`f.contract_id=2` can be put in either the `ON` or the `WHERE`; but (and the optimizer may eliminate any difference), keeping it in the `ON` could *potentially* reduce rows checked in the where, and makes it easier to later convert the query to a `LEFT JOIN` if it is ever needed to find "most recent contacts with no f's of contract_id 2".

Note: Indexing `(franquicia_id, created)` should improve the subquery, and the `IN` used against it; it should also improve the existing JOIN condition on `franquicia_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from this <kbd>[**Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891422/which-is-better-implicit-or-explicit-join)</kbd>

> I personally think the INNER JOIN is better, because it is more
>   readable. It shows better the relations between the table. You got
>   those relations in the join, and you do the filtering in the WHERE
>   clause. This separation makes the query more readable.

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.franquicia_id, 
    f.name, 
    CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) contacto, 
    c.created, 
    DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d-%m-%Y') fecha 
FROM franquicias f
INNER JOIN contacts c ON f.id = c.franquicia_id 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    C2.franquicia_id,
    MAX(C2.created) max_created
    FROM contacts C2 
    GROUP BY C2.franquicia_id
) AS maxCreatedForFrID
ON maxCreatedForFrID.franquicia_id = c.franquicia_id AND maxCreatedForFrID.max_created = c.created
WHERE f.contract_id = 2
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Note:**

A composite index (`franquicia_id,created`) in `contacts` table might boost the performance.

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts` ADD INDEX `idx_contacts_franquicia_id_created` (
    `franquicia_id`,
    `created`
);
```

Comment: Hey, it says :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'C2.franquicia_id
) AS maxCreatedForFrID
ON maxCreatedForFrID.franquicia_id = c' at line 16

Comment: Fixed that typo. Missing by after group

Answer (score 0):

If `franquicias` contains not very lot of records, then next query must be more effective:

```
SELECT c.id, c.franquicia_id, f.name, CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) 
       contacto, c.created, DATE_FORMAT(c.created,'%d-%m-%Y') fecha 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(c2.created) as c2_created, f2.*
    FROM contacts c2
    JOIN franquicias f2 ON f2.id = c2.franquicia_id
) f
JOIN contacts c ON f.id = c.franquicia_id
AND c.created = f.c2_created
WHERE f.contract_id=2 
ORDER BY created DESC 
limit 10
```