# output bill from rent database with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i made a website where customers can rent a maschine for a specified dates.
i use PHP and MYSQL. [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKWsC.jpg) that shows my tables and the desired relations.
i need to output a bill. the bill should contain the customers data, the maschines he rented and the dates he selected. the customer can rent multiple maschines and each maschine can be rented for multiple dates that can be non-consecutive.
how do i make a query that returns all the data i need for the bill?

Comment: Google how to write a MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions is about SQL sentences, no matter if you're using php.

A query as follow will work:

> SELECT a.firstname, b.machine, d.from, d.to FROM rents as a, maschines
>   as b, renInfo as c, rentDates as d WHERE c.rid=a.id AND c.mid=b.id AND
>   c.id=d.riid ORDER BY a.firstname, b.machine, d.from, d.to

Comment: Yay this works. had to change it a bit because you made typos (because i made a typo in the first place on my table name) changed it and now it works. thank you.

Comment: Don't join tables like this.  Use ANSI Join syntax.

Comment: Ok, then, this links would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891422/which-is-better-implicit-or-explicit-join , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where