# Is this the same as JOIN in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

Here is my query:

Does this look efficient? Is there an advantage of using JOIN? Or is this the same?

```
$query_Recordset2 = 
"SELECT cute_news.category, cute_news.id, cute_story.short, cute_story.post_id, cute_news.date, cute_news.url, cute_news.title 
FROM cute_news, cute_story 
WHERE cute_news.id = cute_story.post_id AND category LIKE '10%' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,35";
```

Comment: Define what relation betweeen the tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question might be a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where).

Implicit JOINs do not carry the intent, and are thus less readable.

Your query will lead to strictly same results as:

```
SELECT cute_news.category, cute_news.id, cute_story.short, cute_story.post_id, cute_news.date, cute_news.url, cute_news.title 
FROM cute_news
 INNER JOIN cute_story ON cute_story.post = cute_news.id
WHERE category LIKE '10%' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,35
```

but the latter query is far more readable because you separate JOIN predicates from filters and express the logic behind the query.

Comment: +1 for specially for `Implicit JOINs do not carry the intent, and are thus less readable.`

Answer (score 3):

> The "implicit join notation" simply lists the tables for joining (in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement), using commas to separate them. Thus, it specifies a cross join, and the WHERE clause may apply additional filter-predicates (which function comparably to the join-predicates in the explicit notation)

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join)

In other words it's the same

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the `FROM` clause having multiple tables, comma-separated, then yes, it is basically the same as an `INNER JOIN`.

However, this is old syntax; it is preferred to use `INNER JOIN`, which is more standard.

In addition, the problem with the old syntax is that by combining the joining fields with the rest of the `WHERE` clause, it can make the query hard to read, and in some cases cause extra work for the parser. It is much better to explicitly state the relationships in the `ON` clause for each `JOIN`.