# Whether to use JOIN or not?

Tags: sql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [INNER JOIN versus WHERE clause — any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-versus-where-clause-any-difference)
>   [SQL JOIN: is there a difference between USING, ON or WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where)

For example, I have this `SQL` statement:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM orders, inventory  
 WHERE orders.product = inventory.product
```

or

```
SELECT *  
  FROM orders  
  JOIN inventory  
    ON orders.product = inventory.product
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Using `,` shows someone that follows blindly - Someone who copied what they were shown, but didn't develop themselves enough to find out why they shouldn't be using it.  KUDOS for asking :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing, but I'd recommend the second approach for readability and maintainability.

1. Using `JOIN` allows you to separate the conditions that define *relationships* between tables from conditions which are *filters* on the result set.
2. Using `JOIN` makes it easier to see if you are missing a join condition.
3. Using  `JOIN` allows you to easily choose between `INNER` or `OUTER JOIN`. The comma syntax is equivalent to `INNER JOIN` (though some databases do have an extension to allow an outer join when using the first approach).
4. The most important is to be consistent about which you use. The comma syntax has different precedence from the `JOIN` keyword which can lead to confusing errors if you try to mix the two syntaxes in the same query. Because of point 3, it is easier to be consistent if you always use `JOIN`.

Comment: Points 3 and 4 are important. Implied JOINs (in WHERE) are easler to bollix up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338

Comment: Implied joins area SQL antipattern, there is no excuse for ever using one.

Answer (score 3):

Inner join is ansi syntax, should be the preferred method.

Imagine how ugly this solution could get if you were to use the `,` with say many tables?
`SELECT * FROM orders, inventory, products, logistics, accounting, materials, ...`

Be kind to your future developers and anyone else looking at or maintaining this code use the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Both are ANSI syntax. Explicit JOIN was added with SQL92. The implicit JOIN is SQL89

Answer (score 2):

The comma (`,`) is equivalent to an `CROSS JOIN`.  Using an explicit `CROSS JOIN` is more intuitive and recommended, as it can easily be changed to a `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, etc.  Using `CROSS JOIN` is also ANSI-compliant.

Comment: -1 - The comma is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`, but you make it an `INNER JOIN` by the filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @JNK thanks for the correction, I have edited to reflect.

Answer (score -1):

They are functionally equivalent.  The second one is 'newer'.

Comment: The second is a lot more than "newer" (and by newer we mean it came out almost 20 years ago), it is also less prone to error and far easier to maintain over time especially as things get complicated. The first is syntax that should never be used.

Comment: both were introduced within 4 years of each other - about 20 years ago...  they are functionally equivalent.  you can get off your high horse at any time.