# SQL aggregate query error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, average

I have 3 tables like this

```
player(id,name,age,teamid)
team(id,name,sponsor,totalplayer,totalchampion,boss,joindate)
playerdetail(id,playerid,position,number,allstar,joindate)
```

I want to select teaminfo include name,sponsor,totalplayer,totalchampion,boss,
the average age of the players, the number of the allstar players

I write the t-sql as below

```
SELECT T.NAME,T.SPONSOR,T.TOTALPLAYER,T.TOTALCHAMPION,T.BOSS,T.JOINDATE,
AVG(P.AGE) AS AverageAge,COUNT(D.ALLSTAR) As AllStarPlayer
FROM Team T,Player P,PlayerDetail D 
WHERE T.ID=P.TID AND P.ID=D.PID
```

but it doesn't work, the error message is

> 'Column 'Team.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Who can help me?
Thx in advance!

Comment: What sort of field is playerdetail.allstar? Unless it's NULL when a player is not an allstar, this will return the number of (non-null) playerdetail records, not how many allstars are on a team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
GROUP BY 
      T.NAME,T.SPONSOR,T.TOTALPLAYER,T.TOTALCHAMPION,T.BOSS,T.JOINDATE
```

In most RDBMS (except MySQL which will *guess* for you), a column *must* be either aggregated (`COUNT`, `AVG`) or in the GROUP BY

Also, you should use explicit JOINs. 
This is [clearer, less ambiguous and more difficult to bollix your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/27535)

```
SELECT 
    T.NAME, T.SPONSOR, T.TOTALPLAYER, T.TOTALCHAMPION, T.BOSS, T.JOINDATE,
    AVG(P.AGE) AS AverageAge,
    COUNT(D.ALLSTAR) As AllStarPlayer
FROM 
    Team T
    JOIN
    Player P ON T.ID=P.TID
    JOIN
    PlayerDetail D  ON P.ID=D.PID
GROUP BY 
    T.NAME, T.SPONSOR, T.TOTALPLAYER, T.TOTALCHAMPION, T.BOSS, T.JOINDATE;
```

Comment: Hi, gbn, my all star is bit type, so when the player is not an allstar, the value is 0, I think I can use count() to calculate the total number of allstars. Your t-sql works well. Thanks! My original t-sql as same as yours except without the group by statement, could you tell me why I have to add the group by statement?

Comment: @AI_Bryant: "In most RDBMS (except MySQL which will guess for you), a column must be either aggregated (COUNT, AVG) or in the GROUP BY"

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want this data per team, and team.ID uniquely identifies team, I suggest the following:

```
SELECT max(T.NAME) As TeamName,
       max(T.SPONSOR) As Sponsor,
       max(T.TOTALPLAYER) As TotalPlayers,
       max(T.TOTALCHAMPION) As TotalChampions,
       max(T.BOSS) As Boss,
       max(T.JOINDATE) As JoinDate,
       AVG(P.AGE) AS AverageAge,
       COUNT(D.PID) As AllStarPlayer
FROM Team T
join Player P on T.ID=P.TID 
left join PlayerDetail D on P.ID=D.PID and D.ALLSTAR = 'Y'
group by T.ID
```

Comment: A workaround for a MySQL-addicted developer? :) Actually, I like it, though I'm almost certain that I'll never use it.

Comment: ? Not sure which bit you think is the workaround, or why you mention MySQL specifically... unless it's the use of MAX (where you wouldn't need an aggregate function in MySQL)? I find redundant grouping to be confusing, when trying to understand SQL queries.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the MAXes for the columns that aren't supposed to change since their PK is in the GROUP BY clause. I see your concern, but this abundance of aggregating looks hardly less confusing to me. I mean, if you are used to it, fine. I would aggregate `Player left join PlayerDetail` separately, then join the result set to `Team`, though.

Comment: Through a subquery? Still more confusing (to me), and likely to perform poorly (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT T.NAME,T.SPONSOR,T.TOTALPLAYER,T.TOTALCHAMPION,T.BOSS,T.JOINDATE,
AVG(P.AGE) AS AverageAge,COUNT(D.ALLSTAR) As AllStarPlayer
FROM Team T
JOIN Player P ON T.ID = P.TEAMID
JOIN PlayerDetail D ON P.ID = D.PLAYERID
GROUP BY T.NAME,T.SPONSOR,T.TOTALPLAYER,T.TOTALCHAMPION,T.BOSS,T.JOINDATE
```