# SQL, get foreign key value. Foreign key references the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, key

MS SQL Server database.

I have this simple structure: (sorry about primary keys not in a right places)

[image]

In TEACHER table I have a foreign key "Chief", which references TEACHER.ID (same table). How can I get not an integer(Teacher.ID), but a Name of a Chief(TEACHER.Name for Chief), while doing SELECT query?

This one gets just an integer(ID of a Chief):

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.Name, TEACHER.Name, TEACHER.IDCode, POST.Name, TEACHER.Tel, TEACHER.Salary, TEACHER.Rise, TEACHER.HireDate, Chief
FROM TEACHER, DEPARTMENT, POST
WHERE TEACHER.ID_Post = POST.ID AND
    TEACHER.ID_Department = DEPARTMENT.ID;
GO
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`JOIN` the `TEACHER` table one more time, like so:

```
SELECT 
  d.Name, 
  t.Name, 
  t.IDCode, 
  p.Name, 
  t.Tel, 
  t.Salary, 
  t.Rise, 
  t.HireDate, 
  chief.Name 'Chief Name'
FROM TEACHER t 
INNER JOIN TEACHER chief ON t.Chief = chief.ID
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON t.ID_Department = d.ID
INNER JOIN POST p ON t.ID_Post = p.ID;
```

And use the ANS-SQL-92 `JOIN` syntax instead of the old syntax that you are using in your query. [*They are the same*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289546/which-query-is-the-correct-way/13289653#13289653), but this is the recommended syntax.

Comment: Does SQL server really allow a column alias to be specified with single quotes which denote character literals, not identifiers in SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - As far as I know, Yes it allows a column alias to be specified with single quotes. But I wrote it this way to be formatted as a character literal for the output. But what is your recommendations in this?

Comment: The SQL standard (and all other DBMS if I'm not mistaken) requires identifiers (that contain special characters like a space in this case) to be enclosed with double quotes. So a valid column alias should be written like this: `chief.Name as "Chief Name"`. As SQL Server also understands that syntax I prefer to stick with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.Name, TEACHER.Name, TEACHER.IDCode
    , POST.Name, TEACHER.Tel, TEACHER.Salary, TEACHER.Rise, TEACHER.HireDate, c.Name as ChiefName
    FROM TEACHER
    join DEPARTMENT on TEACHER.ID_Department = DEPARTMENT.ID
    Join POST on TEACHER.ID_Post = POST.ID
    Left Join TEACHER c on c.ID=TEACHER.Chief
```