# MySQL join two tables where WHERE statement from PHP variable already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I normally do a join like this:

```
$query = "SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC ".
     "FROM table1, table2".
        "WHERE table1.uid = table2.uid";
```

But in this case the WHERE portion is already used to specify a record using a PHP variable.  How do I JOIN table 2 in this case?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ColA, ColB FROM Table1 WHERE value = $value
```

Comment: `$sql = 'select * from table1, table2 where table1.uid = table2.uid and value = \''.$value.'\'';` should work if I correctly understood your question.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause). It is usually more readable to use the `JOIN` clause to specify join conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$query = "SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC FROM table1, 
            table2 WHERE table1.uid = table2.uid and table1.value=$value";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
               ON (table1.uid = table2.uid) WHERE table1.value=$value";
```

Comment: Uhm, you're missing the quite important escaping of the value. :)

Comment: The use of () here: ON (table1.uid = table2.uid) was necessary for me to make this work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

They are already joined. It is the same as

```
SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON  table1.uid = table2.uid
```

If you need to add more conditions, add them to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.uid = table2.uid
  AND value = $value;
```

Or, with the ANSI SQL-92 syntax:

```
SELECT table1.ColA, table2.ColC 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON  table1.uid = table2.uid
WHERE  value = $value;
```

**Note that:** You should always use the later syntax, with `JOIN` to join the tables instaed of the `WHERE` clause. It is the recommended way to do this. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289653/722783) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ColA, 
ColB 

FROM table1, table2
WHERE value = $value 
and table1.uid = table2.uid
```

OR YOU CAN JOIN THE TABLES THROUGH

```
SELECT 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ColA, 
ColB 

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.uid = table2.uid
WHERE value = $value
```