# Sum of a activity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables and I are trying to calulate how many sold seats there is for each movie. I still can't get it to work and I only get the total for sold seats for all the movies.

```
Movie:
moveID
mName

Prog:
progID
moveID
showID

Show:
showID
show start
show stop
soldSeats
progID
```

This is one of the codes have been working on:

```
SELECT mName, SUM(soldSeats)
FROM movie, show
WHERE movie.movieID = prog.movieID
AND prog.showID = show.showID
GROUP BY mName
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: is this the sql you have been using? It refers to prog in the where but not as a table.

Comment: I see that I forgot Prog when I wrote it here. I'm sure I used it in the code I used before. Anyway code above works for me now, I do not know what happened, I've spent hours on this little problem :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining with the table `Prog`. Also, you should really use proper explicit joins in your queries.

```
SELECT M.mName, SUM(S.sodSeats) SoldSeats
FROM Movie M
LEFT JOIN Prog P
    ON M.movieID = P.movieID
LEFT JOIN Show S
    ON P.showID = S.showID
GROUP BY M.mName
```

Comment: Can you qualify your last sentance 'you should really use proper explicit joins' - I've seen that mentioned before, what's wrong with the way he's done it?

Comment: @DaveRlz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not get this code to the way it should, it listed all the combination of soldseats, not summarized. However the code I wrote over with the "Prog" is working now.