# Find MAX of grouped SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I have this code and it gives me sold seats summarized for each movie:

```
SELECT mName, SUM(soldSeats)
FROM movie, show, prog
WHERE movie.movieID = prog.movieID
AND prog.showID = show.showID
GROUP BY mName
```

The problem is to find movie that have the max of seats sold, I have tried to add this, but only get no rows:

```
HAVING SUM(soldseats) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(soldseats)) FROM show
GROUP BY solgteplasser)
```

Do anyone have a suggestion? Here is how the tables looks: [Sum of a activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380512/sum-of-a-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select test.* 
from 
(Select movie.mName, SUM(show.soldSeats) as soldseatsum
FROM movie, show, prog
WHere movie.movieId = prog.movieID
AND prog.showID = show.showID
Group by movie.mName
Order by soldseatsum DESC) test
Where rownum<=1
```

This way you order your selection descending by your SUM
and you select the first row only using Rownum 
which is the row with the highest SUm.

EDIT: 
Also in case you got Nulls in your SUM column make sure you add a NULLS LAST after your ORder By like this:

```
.....
.....
Group by movie.mName
    Order by soldseatsum DESC NULLS LAST) test
    Where rownum<=1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, your code worked perfectly. What do "test.*" exactly do? I have not seen this yet, is it some kind of a view?

Comment: Think of your initial Selection as a temporary table called test
I use it to select all of its records that have a rownumber <=1 (which is essentialy the first row only). So Test is just an alias I gave to that selection. It 's not needed so much here since we only select fields from that particular selection. But I use it just to develop good habbits :)