# How many times MySQL iterates table in select query with duplicating the table in from part?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, tree

I have the next query:

```
SELECT
    parent1.name,
    parent2.name
FROM myTable AS child, myTable AS parent1, myTable AS parent2
WHERE
    child.parentId = parent1.id AND
    parent1.parentId = parent2.id;
```

I put the same in `from` block 3 times. Does it means that MySQL will scan the table 3 times?

Comment: Your language is not entirely clear.  MySQL will do two self-joins of the `myTable` table.  Whether it scans, seeks, or something else might depend on the query plan.

Comment: Give this a thorough read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html - it talks about how to get MySQL to tell you how it will execute a query.

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Optimizers in RDBMS generally would ensure that there aren't multiple scans in this case. Indexing would even speed up further! But, for confirming this, you can analyze `Explain` statement result on this query.