# Not sure how to phrase COUNT() statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've have a question to solve:

-list the names of countries where no city has a population over 1,000,000.

(I would think that this would mean that COUNT(name)should pull up names that are equal to zero.  I'm not sure how to phrase that statement.  Here is my code, there are two tables joined.

```
<mysql>SELECT ct.code, ct.fullname, COUNT(name) FROM city AS cy JOIN country AS ct ON cy.country = ct.code 
WHERE cy.population < 1000000 
GROUP BY ct.code 
ORDER BY ct.code ASC; 

+------+---------------------------------------+-------------+
| code | fullname                              | COUNT(name) |
+------+---------------------------------------+-------------+
| ABW  | Aruba                                 |           1 |
| AFG  | Afghanistan                           |           3 |
| AGO  | Angola                                |           4 |
| AIA  | Anguilla                              |           2 |
| ALB  | Albania                               |           1 |
| AND  | Andorra                               |           1 |
| ANT  | Netherlands Antilles                  |           1 |
| ARE  | United Arab Emirates                  |           5 |
```

Comment: The count is an aggregate operator, which will return one row only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cc.name
from city c, country cc
where CountryCode = code
group by cc.name
having MAX(c.population) < 1000000;
```

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

- `Count()` used in your query will simply count all the cities in a country with population less than 1000000. `Where` clause basically returns only those cities which match your given condition (*population less than 1000000*). It does not necessarily imply that **all** the cities of a country are below 1000000.
- You need `Group By` with `Having` clause, in order to check on **all** the cities of a country, such that none of them have `population >= 1000000`

Try the following query:

```
SELECT ct.code, 
       ct.fullname 
FROM city AS cy 
JOIN country AS ct ON cy.country = ct.code 
GROUP BY ct.code, ct.fullname 
HAVING SUM(cy.population > 1000000) = 0 
ORDER BY ct.code ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: I like the answer, but. just had the change the operators.  The question was "where no city", I would think this would mean the less than operator.• < less than, But it seems to work.

Comment: It seems the answers may be off:  I have two tables I am working with city.csv and country.csv.  You should be able to fork them under my data sets. 
https://www.kaggle.com/hashtagkehl/citycsv
https://www.kaggle.com/hashtagkehl/countrycsv

The question that I'm trying to answer is:
-list the names of countries where no city has a population over 1,000,000.
 the results.

+------+-----------+
| code | fullname  |
+------+-----------+
| GIN  | Guinea    |
| HKG  | Hong Kong |
| SGP  | Singapore |
| URY  | Uruguay   |
+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: @ChrisKehl sql statement used ?

Comment: SELECT ct.code, ct.fullname 
    -> FROM city AS cy 
    -> JOIN country AS ct ON cy.country = ct.code 
    -> GROUP BY ct.code, ct.fullname 
    -> HAVING SUM(cy.population < 1000000)= 0
    -> ORDER BY ct.code ASC;

Comment: results:+------+-----------+
| code | fullname  |
+------+-----------+
| GIN  | Guinea    |
| HKG  | Hong Kong |
| SGP  | Singapore |
| URY  | Uruguay   |
+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: @ChrisKehl please check my answer. I am using `>` instead of `<`. I am actually using a negative condition to filter out. That is why you previously misunderstood as well. Basically if no city has population (`> 1000000`), the sum would be zero, and that is what I am checking for.