# mysql query - how to merge tables in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem joining tables in the result column. i have a working query which combine different tables using UNION but when i'm extending another table i got an error saying 'The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns'

this is my query:

```
(SELECT
    IDNumber,
    CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' ', Middle) as Name,
    CONCAT(EmDesignation, ', ', Department) as Information,
    Image,
    v.PlateNo as PlateNumber
FROM
    tblemployee as e, tblvehicle as v
WHERE 
    v.RFIDNo LIKE '6424823943'
AND
    e.RFIDNo LIKE '6424823943')
UNION
(SELECT 
    IDNumber,
    CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName, ' ', Middle) as Name,
    CONCAT(Course, ', ', Year) as Information,
    Image,
    v.PlateNo as PlateNumber
FROM
    tblstudents as s, tblvehicle as v
WHERE
    v.RFIDNo LIKE '6424823943'
AND
    s.RFIDNo LIKE '6424823943')
```

I have problem with this. *Continuation query above*

```
UNION
(SELECT
    Barrier
FROM 
    tblinformation as inf
WHERE
    inf.RFIDNo IN (6424823943)
ORDER BY 
    AttendanceNo DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: When you use UNION the quantity of columns, the order and types, should be the same for all the queries you are making the union.

Comment: can i use another statement to join that columns?

Comment: I think i'm wrong doing UNION... can you give me solution to join that table?

Comment: Please, add sample data and the expected output, so we don't have to guess what you need. If you do this, i will help you with your query.

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states what the problem is. Just improve number of columns in SELECT and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct. Add `NULL`s to your second query to match the column number, and it will work.

For example:

```
SELECT
    Barrier,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM 
    tblinformation as inf
...
```

Comment: I think i'm wrong doing UNION... can you give me solution to join that table?

Comment: it inserted to another row ... I think UNION is not the solution.. can u please help joining it?