# How do i fix the following MYSQL statement?

Tags: mysql

List the number of Judges graduated from each law school.
The tables are `Presidents`, `Judges`, and `Appoints`. `Judges` has columns `JName`, `DateOfBirth`, `LawSchool`. I have tried the following statement and am running into an error I am not sure I understand completely:

```
SELECT jname, COUNT(jname)
FROM Judges J1, Judges J2
WHERE J1.LawSchool = J2.LawSchool AND J1.Jname != J2.Jname;
```

The error is: `ERROR 1052: Column 'jname' in field list is ambiguous`.

Comment: Use `SELECT J1.name`, that is, qualify `name` using one of the aliases.

Comment: Ambiguous means that the column (in this case, the jname) was found in more than one table in the query, so you need to specify which table reference should be used to fetch the column, as Tim said.

Comment: I believe you could use a different statement here, something like `select lawschool, count(*) from judges group by lawschool;`

Comment: Can you show sample data for the `Judges` table along with the expected output?

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

The field `jname` exist in more then one table that you are selecting data from (Judges J1 & Judges J2). You have to specify which table you want this data from. But, according to your task, I think the right way to do this is:

```
SELECT LawSchool, COUNT(*)
FROM Judges
Group By LawSchool
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just fixed my answer, I think that before the fix my whole answer was a mistake.