# MySQL: Select if at least one column between dates

Tags: mysql, select, between

I would like to perform select on joined tables and retrieve those rows, where at least one of four column is between two given dates.

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t1.DateCr AS t1DateCr,
    t1.DateUpd AS t1DateUpd,
    t2.DateCr AS t2.DateCr,
    t2.DateUpd AS t2DateUpd
FROM
    Table1 AS t1,
    Table2 AS t2,
WHERE
    t1.Id = t2.t1Id
  AND (t1.DateCr BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-11-04'
     OR t1.DateUpd BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-11-04'
     OR t2.DateCr BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-11-04'
     OR t2.DateUpd BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-11-04')
GROUP BY t1.Id
```

Can this be written in <s>more elegant way?</s> without repeating the `BETWEEN` condition several times?

I can not use `GREATEST` and `LEAST`, because I dont want to select rows, where dates are bigger and smaller than given range, but not inside it.

And `(t1.DateCr,t1.DateUpd,t2.DateCr,t2.DateUpd) BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-11-04'` does not work.

Comment: Define more elegant.

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: You can use a query that uses `DISTINCT` and `UNION ALL` and you only type the two dates once. But it would only result in a messier query.

Comment: Any time you see a GROUP BY clause absent of any aggregating functions, you can be sure that something's gone very wrong somewhere. Equally, when you see a suggested answer that reiterates the error, the safest course of action is simply to ignore it.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)