# How to get data into data base using shot concept 6(-)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when I want to fetch data from data base 
The problem lies in the use of(-) exemple (code-produit)
With that I can not change anything in data base

Requet:

```
SELECT `Commande.numéro-Commande`,`Date`,`Code-Produit`,`Désignation`,`Prix-Unitaire`,`Qte` 
FROM `client`,`commande`,`produit`,`ligne-commande` 
WHERE `client.Code-client`=`commande.Code-client` and 
      `commande.Numèro-commande`=`ligne-commande.Numèro-commande` and
     `ligne-commande.Code_Produit`=`produit.Code-Produit` and 
     `code-client`=5
```

Error:

[image: The mistake that gets]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use hyphen `-` in your table/column name(s), you should consider wrapping it using backticks. Otherwise, MySQL parser would read it as subtraction operator. My recommendation is to use underscore `_` instead of hyphen `-`.

Secondly, please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

```
SELECT Commande.`numéro-Commande`,
       Date,
       `Code-Produit`,
       Désignation,
       `Prix-Unitaire`,
       Qte 
FROM client 
JOIN commande ON client.`Code-client` = commande.`Code-client`
JOIN produit ON `ligne-commande`.Code_Produit=produit.`Code-Produit`
JOIN `ligne-commande` ON commande.`Numèro-commande` = `ligne-commande`.`Numèro-commande`
WHERE client.`code-client` = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the table for the last **code-client** (*code-client=5*), it could be from **client** or **commande**, so set the table