# SQL - #1093 - Table '' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, updates

I have this code:

```
UPDATE WORLD_TEST 
SET PROGRAMMER = (SELECT (RECURSE_HOUR/360) 
                  FROM WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER, WORLD_TEST 
                  WHERE LVL = LVL_PROGRAMMER) 
WHERE (SELECT MAX_RECURSE 
       FROM WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER, WORLD_TEST 
       WHERE LVL = LVL_PROGRAMMER) 
>= 
(PROGRAMMER+(SELECT (RECURSE_HOUR/360) 
             FROM WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER, WORLD_TEST 
             WHERE LVL = LVL_PROGRAMMER));
```

With this error:

> 1093 - Table 'WORLD_TEST' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

**EDIT (clarification from comments):** `PROGRAMMER` and `LVL_PROGRAMMER` is from `WORLD_TEST` table, and `RECURSE_HOUR`, `LVL`, `MAX_RECURSE` is from `WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER` table.

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Error message is quite clear, that you cannot use the sample table twice in `update` clause. There are other ways to achieve that, like using Derived Tables. But your current query in itself is extremely convoluted

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do with relevant sample data, and expected output.

Comment: I want to update the resources based in other table and if the resources doesn't exceed the allowed limit

Comment: RECURSE_HOUR, LVL, LVL_PROGRAMMER, MAX_RECURSE are columns in which table, respectively ?

Comment: PROGRAMMER and LVL_PROGRAMMER is from WORLD_TEST and RECURSE_HOUR, LVL,  MAX_RECURSE is from WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is quite clear, that you cannot use the same table in the `UPDATE` clause as well as the source of a subquery. There are other ways to achieve that, like using Derived Tables, etc. In this particular case, you simply need to `JOIN` between the two tables.

Also, please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and switch to Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

In case of multi-table queries, it is recommended to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for code readability and avoiding ambiguous behavior.

Based on your further clarification in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223078/sql-1093-table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as/53223357#comment93333255_53223078), try the following:

```
UPDATE WORLD_TEST AS wt 
JOIN WORLD_TEST_PROGRAMMER AS wtp 
  ON wt.LVL_PROGRAMMER = wtp.LVL 
SET wt.PROGRAMMER = wtp.RECURSE_HOUR
WHERE wtp.MAX_RECURSE >= (wt.PROGRAMMER + (wtp.RECURSE_HOUR/360))
```

Comment: @Victor These are aliases. It is recommended to use them in multi-table queries for code readability and avoiding ambiguous behaviour. Refer this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/