# What's wrong with this stored procedure (nested SELECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is throwing a syntax error on the first SELECT - why?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_cand_by_pos_skill`(IN id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT *  FROM candidates 
WHERE cid = ANY(SELECT candid FROM positionskills p, candidate_skills s WHERE p.positionid = id and s.skillid = p.skill);
END
```

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: So which part of the query needs to change?

Comment: `FROM positionskills p, candidate_skills s`

Comment: Did you remember to change the delimiter before you attempted to define the procedure i.e. `DELIMITER // CREATE ...`

Comment: Madhur, thanks, what would the correct syntax be?

Comment: And please use `IN` instead of `= ANY`, it's much easier to understand for most people.

Comment: dnoeth that fixed the error, thank you

Answer (score 0):

- You need to define the Delimiter to something else (eg: `$$`) other than `;`. At the end redefine back to `;`
- Please do not use comma based Implicit joins. These are obsolete and error-prone. Please switch to modern `JOIN .. ON` based syntax.
- Switch to `IN` instead of `= ANY`:

Try the following instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_cand_by_pos_skill`(IN id INT)
BEGIN

SELECT *  
FROM candidates 
WHERE cid IN (SELECT candid 
              FROM positionskills p 
              JOIN candidate_skills s ON s.skillid = p.skill
              WHERE p.positionid = id);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```