# Query a ranking number extremely fast in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Database has the following columns:
id, uuid, trophies

In order to get the ranking number of a player based on trophies, I currently use this query:

```
 SELECT rank FROM (SELECT (@num := @num +1) as rank, uuid FROM User, 
 (SELECT @num := 0) x ORDER BY trophies DESC) as TMP WHERE 
 uuid=UNHEX('7c6d37759dd749349f2c32303a367226');
```

However, the query takes around 1.3 seconds due to the size of the database (300,000 players).

Is there a more efficient method on getting the rank number in MySQL?

---

Here's the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`uuid` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL, `trophies` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57917982 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

EXPLAIN statement:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Please share the indexing details on your database. Do you have an integer Primary key ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using (5.7, 8.0 ...)?.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, I have a primary key.
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @wchiquito Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: @Bob do you have any indexes defined ? Please edit the question and add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement result. Also, `EXPLAIN` statement results can be helpful as well.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya done! added both

Comment: @Bob please add indexing to `trophies` column and check again.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya added. same thing, takes 1.3 seconds (KEY `trophies` (`trophies`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

This query is at least 10,000x faster.

```
SELECT 1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User a WHERE a.trophies > b.trophies) AS rank 
FROM User b WHERE uuid = UNHEX('7c6d37759dd749349f2c32303a367226') ORDER BY 
rank LIMIT 1;
```