# SET two variables in SELECT statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using below code which is executing in mysql but giving error while hitting through java program as java program cannot read semicolons ... for java these are 3 statements . I need to execute this query (  setting both variable and then selecting in one query):

```
set @row_number:=0;set @PROMOTION_ID_NO:='';
SELECT 
     @row_number:=CASE 
        WHEN @PROMOTION_ID_NO=PD.PROMOTION_ID THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS SEQ,
     @PROMOTION_ID_NO:=PD.PROMOTION_ID AS PROMOTION_ID,
    PD.CONDITION_CODE,
    PM.PROMOTION_code,
    PD.CONDITION_TYPE
FROM
    POS_PROMOTION_DISCOUNT PD , POS_PROMOTION_MASTER PM WHERE 
    PD.PROMOTION_ID = PM.PROMOTION_ID
AND PD.STORE_NO = 'G121';
```

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? Please give feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- You can move the `SET` statement(s) to a separate [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and do a `CROSS JOIN` of that table with the other table(s).
- Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308). I have changed to use `JOIN .. ON` instead.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
     @row_number:=CASE 
                    WHEN @PROMOTION_ID_NO=PD.PROMOTION_ID THEN @row_number + 1
                    ELSE 1
                  END AS SEQ,
     @PROMOTION_ID_NO:=PD.PROMOTION_ID AS PROMOTION_ID,
    PD.CONDITION_CODE,
    PM.PROMOTION_code,
    PD.CONDITION_TYPE
FROM
    POS_PROMOTION_DISCOUNT PD 
JOIN POS_PROMOTION_MASTER PM ON PD.PROMOTION_ID = PM.PROMOTION_ID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT row_number:=0, @PROMOTION_ID_NO:='') AS user_init 
WHERE 
  PD.STORE_NO = 'G121';
```