# Getting empty set from SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I get am empty set when I enter this SQL statement, could someone please tell me why?

```
select ayr,mods.mid,mtitle,credits 
from mods,comp 
where mods,mid = comp.mid and ayr = 2001/02;
```

It displays the right thing when omitting 'ayr = 2001/02'.

Comment: Even if you remove `ayr = ..`, your query is syntactically wrong. It should be `where mods.mid = ..` you have a comma instead.

Comment: Hi michelle. Welcome to StackOverflow!. you have to enclose date values in single quotes, and also format your date values like so: `2001-02`

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: What does your DB have for `ayr`? Also what do you intend for `2001/02` to mean? Perhaps `and ayr regexp '^200[12]$'` is what you mean

Comment: the comma was a mistake I made while typing the post, sorry. Ahmad could you please elaborate?

Comment: ayr stands for academic year, and yes it is in the DB, 2001/02 is the academic year

Comment: try ayr = '2001/02'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the date

```
select ayr,mods.mid,mtitle,credits 
from mods,comp 
where mods,mid = comp.mid and ayr = '2001/02';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that after the `where` clause it should be `mods,mid` instead of `mods.mid`, table name is not entered in the correct way after `SELECT` statement

As per my suggestion you should enter `mods.mid`

Try this Syntax:-

```
select ayr,mods,mtitle,credits from mods,comp where mods.mid = comp.mid and ayr = 2001/02;
```

Post the output

Comment: It returns Empty set, but when doing ayr = '2001/02' it works.

Comment: Yes you're right, date/time and timestamp datatypes require quotation marks, just like strings. My mistake I didn't notice it at the first sight