# Trying to update a column in a different table with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am grabbing 1000 records of data with this query:

```
SELECT
     RIGHT(tagarr, LENGTH(tagarr) - LENGTH('encoder:')) enc, mo.src_ip, mo.datacenter
FROM
    logical_service ls, mpeg_out mo, UNNEST(ls.tags) AS tagarr
WHERE
    tagarr LIKE 'encoder:%'
    AND mo.lid = ls.lid
```

That creates 3 columns of data that looks like this:

```
encoder | src_ip | datacenter
```

I then have an `encoder` table that has fields

```
encoder | output_source_ip | datacenter
```

the output_source_ip is primarily null, so I want to update that column on the `encoder` table with src_ip if the select on encoder and datacenter matches with encoder and datacenter.

Any idea how I can do this? Here is my attempt at doing it, but it is definitely broken:

```
UPDATE encoder 
    SET output_source_ip = (
SELECT
     RIGHT(tagarr, LENGTH(tagarr) - LENGTH('encoder:')) encoder, mo.src_ip, mo.datacenter
FROM
    logical_service ls, mpeg_out mo, UNNEST(ls.tags) AS tagarr
WHERE
    tagarr LIKE 'encoder:%'
    AND mo.lid = ls.lid
);
```

Comment: `UNNEST()` does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Please show an example of the data and the desired result for that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `WITH` statement in this to make things look cleaner

```sql
WITH 
source_data as (
SELECT
     RIGHT(tagarr, LENGTH(tagarr) - LENGTH('encoder:')) enc, mo.src_ip, mo.datacenter
FROM
    logical_service ls, mpeg_out mo, UNNEST(ls.tags) AS tagarr
WHERE
    tagarr LIKE 'encoder:%'
    AND mo.lid = ls.lid )

UPDATE encoder as en
    SET output_source_ip = (
    select src_ip from source_data as sd
    where sd.datacenter = en.datacenter and sd.encoder = en.encoder
)
```

That should do the job for you

Comment: The use of `WITH` requires MySQL 8.0.  @Jay266, what version are you using?

Comment: Since, OP has accepted this as an answer, he is using MySQL 8.0+

Answer (score 2):

One way is to utilize a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery), to fetch the `src_ip` values, and then `JOIN` to the `encoder` table on `datacenter` and `encoder` fields; and update the values, if there is a match.

Also, please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308). I have changed your `SELECT` query to use Explicit `JOIN .. ON` syntax.

```
UPDATE encoder AS e 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    RIGHT(tagarr, LENGTH(tagarr) - LENGTH('encoder:')) AS encoder, 
    mo.src_ip, 
    mo.datacenter
  FROM
    logical_service AS ls 
    JOIN mpeg_out AS mo ON mo.lid = ls.lid 
    JOIN UNNEST(ls.tags) AS tagarr ON tagarr LIKE 'encoder:%'
) AS dt ON dt.encoder = e.encoder 
           AND dt.datacenter = e.datacenter 
SET e.output_source_ip = dt.src_ip 
WHERE e.output_source_ip IS NULL
```