# How to select and count data from three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have three tables

```
1 - Products 
2- Orders
3- Order_item
```

Table (Products)

```
ID | Product_name | 
--------------------
1  | Samsung Galaxy
```

Table (Orders)

```
ID | Client_name 
-------------------
1  | Admin
```

Table (Orders_item)

```
ID | Order_ID | Product_ID | Quantity 
-------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1          | 1

2  | 1        | 1          | 1 

3  | 1        | 1          | 1
```

I want to select product name , client name and number of quantities when order is 1. I have tried this query

```
SELECT products.name,orders.order_id,orders.client_name,order_item.quantity COUNT(*) FROM products,orders,order_item WHERE products.id = order_item.product_id AND orders.order_id = order_item.order_id AND orders.order_id=1
```

Which returns result like

```
Name | Order_ID | Client_name | Quantity 
----------------------------------------
Sa..| 1         | Admin       | 1 
Sa..| 1         | Admin       | 1 
Sa..| 1         | Admin       | 1
```

I want to get the the result like

```
Samsung | 1 | Admin | 3
```

Someone please help me .

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. See about JOINs. And then see about GROUP BY.

Comment: To give context to Strawberry's comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit JOIN based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Also, Hint: You need to `GROUP BY` on order and product. Worth looking a tutorial on GROUP BY in SQL

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT products.Product_name AS Name,
       orders.id AS Order_ID,
       orders.client_name AS Client_name,
       SUM(order_item.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_item 
ON order_item.Product_ID = products.ID
LEFT JOIN orders
ON orders.ID = order_item.Order_ID
WHERE orders.id=1
GROUP BY products.Product_name,
         orders.id,
         orders.client_name
```

This outputs :

```
| Name           | Order_ID | Client_name | Quantity |
| -------------- | -------- | ----------- | -------- |
| Samsung Galaxy | 1        | Admin       | 3        |
```

Note that [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) can be a good reading too.